# Huge lookup table in SV/UVM

Tags: uvm

I have to build a big lookup table (~14k entries with strings as keys) by parsing an input file for a predictor. Am I better off using an associative array or use uvm_config_db from simulation performance point of view?

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little better. How may components/objects are going to be referencing this table? Can the components modify the table and is seen by others components?

Comment: Only one component (the checker/scoreboard) will be accessing it and the table would be "read-only". No modifications once built. Background: I'm verifying a signal router of sorts (complex network of wires feeding muxes). I have access to a document/file which lists out all possible connections between input and output (runs into thousands) and the configuration pattern (as a string) for each path. I want to build a lookup table using this file with the configuration as the key and the path as a string value stored in the lookup table. The configuration can change with seed/test.

Comment: Yes I think associative arrays will be helpful for large lookup storages.

Comment: I can make no judgment about relative performance, but what about the `uvm_resource_db`? That would be a better choice that the `uvm_config_db`, I would have thought, because `uvm_resource_db` is a general purpose key-value database. But an associative array is even more general purpose...

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. For now, just selecting the those paths I need (about a 100-150 entries approx) from an input file and building a lookup table with associative arrays is working fine (no observable performance hit). Need to see how it behaves when paths get doubled or tripled (At most I can have about 700 paths enabled). We do have an elaborate DPI setup. The current solution will hold till I work on enhancing DPI to provide lookup for huge tables (future compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is only one component, I'd use an associative array.

If it were multiple components, I'd be more inclined to put the the entire associative array in one class object, then register that class to the uvm_config_db. This they all components accessing the table are pointing to the same object; thereby limiting the memory footprint.

Still, loading the table may be a bit resource incentive and holding the table will likely require your simulator to use a lot of RAM. If you are only going to need a couple hundred or less entries per test/seed, I suggest loading only the entries you may need into the associative array; not the whole thing.

If you need the whole thing, then it probable will be worth figuring out how to put the table into a real database and use DPI or VPI to access it form simulation. DPI typicality has less overhead. Some tool-sets have IP for accessing memory images and other large data structures that you may be able to utilize.

Comment: I'm inclined towards selectively loading the entries I need but hadnt thought from the DPI angle. Thanks! Will explore that option in detail. Also it scales better I guess if the database grows as compared to local associative array or uvm_config_db. Appreciate your input!

Comment: @vivek , you are satisfied with the answer, please check the "accept this answer" icon to help others with a similar questions